# I am getting wrong result for this simple vowel counter

Tags: arrays, c, string

i am trying to get the number of vowels, but it prints the wrong number most of the time, for example i inputed "ccc" but got "vowel=2"?
what exactly did i do wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char word[20];
    int vowel=0;
    puts("enter word to check number of vowels");
    fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin);
    for (int character=0;character<sizeof(word);character++)
     {
         if (word[character]=='a'||word[character]=='e'||
            word[character]=='i'||word[character]=='o'||
            word[character]=='u'||word[character]=='A'||
            word[character]=='E'||word[character]=='I'||
            word[character]=='O'||word[character]=='U')
                vowel++;
     }
     printf("vowels=%d",vowel);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(word)` is always `20` regardless of the input. So it is counting some junk which is coming after `"ccc"`

Comment: Change `char word[20];` to `char word[20] = {0};` to ensure the whole array is zeroed before using it.

Comment: use either `toupper()` (or `tolower()`) to simplify you logical evaluations, i.e. `if(tolower(word[character]) == 'a' ||...||tolower(word[character]) == 'u' )` (5 segments instead of 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than iterate to the size of the buffer, iterate to the end of the input *string*.  No need to call `strlen()`, just look for the *null character*.

```
// for (int character=0;character<sizeof(word);character++)
for (int character=0; word[character]; character++)
```

Test `fgets()` result to insure something was read.  `fgets()` returns `NULL` when nothing was read or an input error.

```
// fgets(word,sizeof(word),stdin);
if (fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin)) {
  for (int character=0; word[character]; character++)
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong thing to get the length of the string.  `sizeof(word)` is the size in bytes of the entire buffer.  However, `fgets` did not initialize all those values so you have undefined behavior.

Use `strlen(word)` to get the length of a string.

Note you could also simplify your vowel test:

```
if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", word[character])) vowel++;
```

Comment: or at least initialize the `word` array with `char word[20] = {}`

Comment: Sure, but that's a bit of an anti-pattern because the root cause of the problem is testing characters past the end of the string.

Comment: thank you however i am still getting an issue, now it gives less vowels than inputted. for example, i inputted "ahmadabu" and got vowel=2

Comment: @karamalqussiri: Make sure you're entering fewer than 19 characters, or increase the size of `word`.

Comment: @paddy i'm not sure that `fgets` put a null byte at the end. EDIT: i tested and it does not put one if there is no input.

Comment: what @LTBS46 suggested worked perfectly, thank you all .

Comment: @LTBS46: ["If bytes are read and no errors occur, **writes a null character** at the position immediately after the last character written to str."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) EDIT: Yes, it may not be null terminated if nothing was read.

Comment: would you  mind clarifying how the strchr function works as you wrote above, meaning how does that simplification work? thank you in advance

Comment: @karamalqussiri: Read https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr

Comment: @LTBS46 -  What is it you are intending with `char word[20] = {}`?

Comment: @LTBS46 `char word[20] = {}` is not valid standard C.  Perhaps `char word[20] = {0}`.  Initializing `word[]` is indeed an anti-pattern.  If that "fixed" OP's problem, there is something else wrong too.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica what might that be and what do you mean by antipattern?

Comment: @karamalqussiri As paddy and I answered, iterate to the length of the string that was written, not the entire buffer.  If anything, its faster.  Use the return value of `fgets()` to determine if the buffer is good to read.  When `fgets()` returns `NULL`, the buffer may be in an indeterminant state.  Pre-filling with zeros is not sufficient - thus _anti_ to what should be done.

Comment: `if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", word[character])) vowel++;` is a _good_ alternative code when iterating does not include the _null character_ as suggested by paddy.  Otherwise `if (strchr("aeiouAEIOU", '\0')` is always true.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ok so if i understand correctly, instead of "sizeof" i should use strlrn() or do as the other answer and use word[character, or use !='/0' to stop it before the null character if 20 characters were not entered, also use" if (fgets(word,.......))" before for statement to test if a value was entered? or did you mean something else by "use the return value of fgets() to determine  if the buffer is good to read"?

Comment: @karamalqussiri Yes, you got it.